# SQL - filter values based on month & date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I'm currently strugeling to get something done.

I needed only the rows where the date is between a certain date and month.

Example show only the rows where the date is between `01/05` (DD/MM) and `08/07` (DD/MM) the date can be found in the table `tasks` within the field information.
The year can't make any sense, but the results may only between those two dates in that year.

I've tried:

- `BETWEEN (TO_DATE ('01/05','DD/MM') AND (TO_DATE('08/07', 'DD/MM')`
- `EXTRACT (DD/MM) from information`.

none of those are working for me, I hope that someone of you can help me to figure this out!.

Thanks!

Comment: Try where TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(yourColumn, 'MMDD')) between 0501 and 0708;

Comment: Dates normally also have year.  Are you looking for dates in any year, or the current year?

Comment: Show the sample results with query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to disregard the year.  If so, then I would recommend:

```
TO_CHAR(datecol, 'MM/DD') BETWEEN '05/01' AND '07/08'
```

In order for `BETWEEN` to work in this case, you need the format in the order of MM-DD.

If you want this for a particular year, then use direct date comparisons:

```
datecol >= DATE '2018-05-01' AND
datecol < DATE '2018-07-09'  -- note this is one day later
```

Oracle dates have a time component, so you need to be careful when making comparisons.